# Setting Repeat for AnimatorSet in Code

Tags: android, animation

I'm working with AnimatorSets in Android but can't figure out for the life of me how you set the repeat in code. What method do you call on an AnimatorSet to set an arbitrary repeat, or am I going about it wrong? I must be missing something...!

Many thanks

Comment: do not add tags to subject: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score -2):

In general try to avoid AnimationSet. AnimationSet is broken badly (i.e. [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17662)). Some things works from XML, other do not. I personally ended up with own animation code that utilizes AnimationListener to build complex animations without need to use set.

Some quickly fount [tutorial about that approach](http://androidblogger.blogspot.com/2009/01/chaining-two-animations-or-how-to.html).

Comment: Damn, I was afraid of that! I've been using the same thing with the AnimationListener but it feels like such a hack! For all Google get right, that get a fair amount wrong :(